# Postgres column not present after insert

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a postgres database with a quite large table (100GB+)

That table contains gemetry information. And those also have an index.

Now I'd like to add a new column. I do that like so:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN my_new_column geometry DEFAULT null;
```

and postgres confirms it immediately.
When I now to something like:

```
SELECT * from my_table limit 1;
```

it will complain saying that column `my_new_column` does not exist.

I can though DROP that column without a problem and then my SELECT works again.

I thought maybe the ALTER-Insert just takes longer, but when I look at the processes on my machine, it's idle.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Is that plain PostgreSQL or do you use a fork? What extensions are installed?

Comment: You mean you're getting an error message saying that a column does not exist in a `select * from table` statement? I didn't even know it was possible, since  `*` should show all columns available:)

Comment: The error message in in german... but I'll translate it:

Query 1 ERROR: FEHLER:  Column »way_gen10« existiert nicht
CONTEXT:  Remote SQL command: SELECT gid, id, height, geom, way_gen10 FROM public.cont100
It is PostgreSQL with Postgis extension installed
And yes... I make my SELECT with *
Thx for your help guys!

Comment: If a `select *` fails with such an error message, maybe column level grants are used for that table that do not include the new column?

Comment: Maybe the table is partitioned?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name THANK YOU!!! Yes... I had a FOREIGN TABLE access my table. That was the problem. If you create an answer I can accept it! Thanks a lot!